# How to automate recoding using info of a code dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have no problem recoding variables `v1` and `v2` of dataframe `df` into `df2`.
But I have several variables to recode, and it would be easy if I put recoding info into another dataframe (`df3`) and using some kind of loop to recode df using info from `df3`. I have tried several solutions without success.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3),
  v2 = c(2, 3, 1, 1)
)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(v1 = factor(v1, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("red", "blue", "green"))) %>%
  mutate(v2 = factor(v2, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("white", "pale", "black")))


# recoding df using levels
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(v1=case_when(v1 %in% levels(v1)[1:2] ~ "Bad",
                               v1 %in% levels(v1)[3] ~ "Good")) %>%
  mutate(v2=case_when(v2 %in% levels(v2)[1] ~ "Low",
                               v2 %in% levels(v2)[2:3] ~ "High"))

# df3 contains transformation codes for df
# I want to use this info to automate recoding of df
df3 <- data.frame(
  vs = c("v1", "v1", "v2", "v2"), # variables
  ls = c("1:2", "3", "1", "2:3"), # levels
  lb = c("Bad", "Good", "Low", "High") # new labels
)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the sequence in `ls` column of `df3` and create a separate row for each number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df4 <- df3 %>%  
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_ls = list(eval(parse(text = ls)))) %>%
  unnest(new_ls) %>%
  select(-ls)
df4

#   vs    lb    new_ls
#  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#1 v1    Bad        1
#2 v1    Bad        2
#3 v1    Good       3
#4 v2    Low        1
#5 v2    High       2
#6 v2    High       3
```

Get `df` in long format and join with `df4` and get data back in wide format

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'vs', values_to = 'new_ls') %>%
  left_join(df4, by = c('vs', 'new_ls')) %>%
  group_by(vs) %>%
  mutate(new_ls = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = vs, values_from = lb) %>%
  select(-new_ls)

#   v1    v2   
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 Bad   High 
#2 Bad   High 
#3 Bad   Low  
#4 Good  Low
```

Comment: I got an error when joining `df4` with `df` : ```Error: Can't join on `x$new_ls` x `y$new_ls` because of incompatible types.
i `x$new_ls` is of type <factor<2c9da>>>.
i `y$new_ls` is of type <double>>.```

Comment: That happens because `df` variables are factors. When I change those variables to numeric the answer is right.

Comment: Yes, if you have column of different types it will return an error while joining. Are you on R < 4.0.0 or using different data?

Comment: I am using R 4.0.2. The problem is that as you can see in my question, the variables in `df` are transformed into factors. This happens because in my real problem the dataframe I use contains factor variables.